Unable to connect to AWS EC2 server from github action workflow using ssh
I am trying to automate the deployment process of my project. I have a workflow file (yaml) in which I am trying to run ssh command. The private key, IP address of host are stored in secrets. Before calling ssh, I am doing all the necessary preparations, like creating a .ssh directory on the github runner's home directory, creating a privatekey file into which I am writing the key from the secrets, creating a known_hosts file and populating it with ssh-keyscan of the host server, modifying the permissions of the directory and the files. However, I keep getting the following error:
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
I have tried using appleboy/ssh-action@master, but no success. I get the following error:
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
I have tried the remedies suggested on the appleboy/ssh-action@master, such as checking the permissions of directories, files, creating known_hosts2 file.
Note that I am able to successfully run the ssh command from PowerShell prompt. I get connected to the AWS EC2 server successfully.
When searching about this issue on the net (stackexchange, serverfault, github etc.), it appears that this has been a persistent problem over the years. Several workarounds have been suggested, and it appears they had worked for some people in the past. However, none of them seem to work anymore.
Having spent a couple of days already on this problem, I am a little frustrated. I can't understand why github runner wouldn't have a way to ssh into a host, when the whole purpose of github actions is CI/CD.
Can someone share an insight to the current state of this problem and a solution.

Note that I am able to successfully run the ssh command from PowerShell prompt. I get connected to the AWS EC2 server successfully.
I have tried using appleboy/ssh-action@master, but no success. I get the following error:
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

I have tried the remedies suggested on the appleboy/ssh-action@master, such as checking the permissions of directories, files, creating known_hosts2 file.
3. I have tried ssh with -tt option, as well as -o permitTTY=force.

I faced something similar a few weeks back and after struggling for a few hours the only thing that worked was replacing the keypair.
Try generating a new keypair and give it a try, might help.
